# What defines the order of script execution in VS2012 Database Project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, database-project

There are several types of scripts in database project: `PreDeployment`, `PostDeployment`, `Build` and `NotInBuild`.
Whereas the first two can exist only in a single copy, build scripts can be in abundance.

I cannot find the information when and in what order buid scripts are executed.
Does it imply that build scripts mustn't depend on the order of execution or I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

You can have one script marked as "PreDeployment" and one script marked as "PostDeployment". Those scripts will use SQLCMD syntax to include other scripts (build type "none") as part of that process.

The pre-deploy script will be compiled to include all scripts included in the order you specify. The Post-deploy script will be compiled in the same manner.

To include a file in the pre or post deploy script, you use a syntax like:

```
:r .\IncludeThisScript.sql
```

When you publish, the Pre-deploy script will run first, then the DB changes will be made, then the post-deploy script will run.  It's also worth noting that the DB Change script is generated with no knowledge of what the pre/post deploy scripts will do or have done. If you create a table in the pre-deploy script and also try to create it in the project, the project will likely fail because the table already exists.

Comment: and what about build scripts?

Comment: If you mean the actual script to change the database, that's completely controlled by the internals. To my knowledge, the only thing you can do to affect that order is manually edit a generated script. It's usually pretty good about not doing something completely off the wall.

Comment: Then it is better to create build scripts which do not rely on the execution order...

Comment: Well, you don't create the build script. You handle the pre and post deploy scripts. The main build script is auto-generated. You control what happens before and after, as well as the order. Sometimes you need to control that order - as when you're inserting data in tables that are related or if you need to convert data in a certain order.

Comment: But I can add new script with Build type. At least VS allows it.

Comment: Those scripts become part of your project. SQL will try to incorporate them into creating or modifying your database somehow. I've not tried to just add a random script of type "build" to a project to see what would happen. I've always used those for tables, indexes, etc.  DAC will then control the order of creation for those.